# Flash messages do not display because of redirection in Slim

Tags: php, slim

I am working on a Slim 3 application which uses Slim Flash to display flash messages. All tests with a normal setup work fine. However, I added a middleware to my application to shift to HTTPS (and back to HTTP) when entering or leaving protected pages such as sign in or sign up.

The problem is that when I leave the sign up page (HTTPS) and redirect to the home page (HTTP) the flash message saying that the account was created successfully never displays. I tried disabling the middleware (so working only between HTTP pages) and it worked.

This is the code I'm using in the middleware:

```
if($request->getUri()->getScheme() === 'https' && !in_array($request->getUri()->getPath(), self::SSL_REQUIRED_PATHS ) ){
$response = $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', 'http://' . $request->getUri()->getHost() . $request->getUri()->getBasePath() . '/' . $request->getUri()->getPath() );

}
```

Apparently the Response With Status is causing the flash message to get lost. Is there anyway to save the flash message and display it after shifting back to HTTP from HTTPS?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered enabling https for all pages? This is the route most organizations are taking these days.

Comment: I want to second what @commanderZiltoid said. Your site is NOT secure if you're not using HTTPS everywhere. When you only use it on sign in pages it prevents that password from being send in plain text, but the session can still be hijacked in any subsequent request to a non-HTTPS page.

Comment: I went ahead and enabled https across the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a verificiation of flash messages in your middleware redirect and save the message for the next request, something like this maybe:

```
if ($request->getUri()->getScheme() === 'https' &&
    !in_array($request->getUri()->getPath(), self::SSL_REQUIRED_PATHS)
    ) {
    $messagesFlash = $app->flash->getMessages();

    if ($messagesFlash) {
        array_map(function($k, $v) use ($app) {
            $app->flash->addMessage($k, $v);
        }, array_keys($messagesFlash), $messagesFlash);
    }

    $location = sprintf('http://%s%s/%s'
        $request->getUri()->getHost(),
        $request->getUri()->getBasePath(),
        $request->getUri()->getPath()
    );

    $response = $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location',  $location);

}
```

But I recommend use HTTPS in your total website